# Not able to get AWS X-Ray Traces when used with Spring boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

We have a service where we listen to the port using spring integration and fetch the data and place that in AWS SQS. we are trying to use the AWS X-Ray for distributed tracing. But we are getting the below Error.

ERROR o.s.c.a.m.l.QueueMessageHandler - processHandlerMethodException - Unhandled exception from message handler method
com.amazonaws.xray.exceptions.SubsegmentNotFoundException: Failed to end subsegment: subsegment cannot be found.

find below the code:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public Filter TracingFilter() {
        return new AWSXRayServletFilter("ingestion");
    }
}
```

XRay Inspector:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class XRayInspector extends AbstractXRayInterceptor {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, Map<String, Object>> generateMetadata(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Subsegment subsegment) {
        return super.generateMetadata(proceedingJoinPoint, subsegment);
    }
    @Override
    @Pointcut("@within(com.amazonaws.xray.spring.aop.XRayEnabled) && bean(*)")
    public void xrayEnabledClasses() {}
}
```

SQSMessageProcessor:

```
@Service
@EnableIntegration
@EnableRetry
@XRayEnabled
public class SQSMessageProcessor {
 public void sendAndProcessMessage(String message) {
  
}
}
```

pom:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>      

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

we are trying in the local system that is outside the AWS by passing the secret and access key which has permission to AWS X-Ray.
Can you please let us know what are we missing here.